# php code not understood

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, dialog

Everyone Hi. I have a piece of php code that I do not understand and require as detailed explanation as possible. I have pasted the code below:

```
 $customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'];
        if (isset($_POST['group'])){
            $group_id = $_POST['group'];
            $this->db->where('customer_id',$customer_id);
            $query = $this->db->get('customer');
            $row = $query->row();
            $customer_group_id = $row->group_id;
            if ($customer_group_id != $group_id){
            $this->db->where('customer_id',$customer_id);
            $this->db->update('customer',array("group_id" => $group_id));
            }
        }
```

I am new to php and web. Please help me as much as possible. Thank you to you all in advance for your time and help. My question may not be good but please forgive me.

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: codeigniter framework

Comment: Can u answer or explain - Daan - Thank you - Daan

Comment: what does you not understand? code or buisness logic?

Comment: code - Thank you - donald123

Comment: I don't even know PHP and I find it fairly readable. You should specify what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking at some POSTed inputs (presumably from a HTML form submission?):

```
$_POST['customer_id']
$_POST['group']
```

If there is a `group` parameter in the submission, save the posted value in `$group_id`...

```
if (isset($_POST['group'])){
    $group_id = $_POST['group'];
    ...
```

...and get the customer details from the database using the posted `$customer_id`:

```
$customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'];
...

$this->db->where('customer_id',$customer_id);
$query = $this->db->get('customer');
$row = $query->row();
```

Check if the group_id database field is different to the one that was posted:

```
$customer_group_id = $row->group_id;
if ($customer_group_id != $group_id){
     ...
```

If it's different, update the database record for the customer:

```
$this->db->where('customer_id',$customer_id);
$this->db->update('customer',array("group_id" => $group_id));
```